# Battleship code not working

Tags: java

This is my attempt at recreating Battleship using Java. I decided to test the simpler version of the game with only one ship and giving the ship a concrete location on the game board. I found a problem with my code. No matter what coordinate I enter, I end up "hitting" the ship.

Here is all the code I have written so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class GameBoard {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);                                         // scanner object

    String[][] board = {                                                            // game board

    {"_", " 1", " 2", " 3", " 4", " 5", " 6", " 7", " 8", " 9", "10"},      
    {"A", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]"},
    {"B", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]"},
    {"C", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]"},
    {"D", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]"},            
    {"E", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]"},
    {"F", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]"},
    {"G", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]"},
    {"H", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]"},
    {"I", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]"},
    {"J", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]"}

    };

    boolean frigateIsAlive = true;                                                  // the ship is still alive

    int numOfHitsOnFrigate = 0;                                                     // number of hits the player made on the frigate

    String [] frigate = {board[1][1], board[1][2]};                                 // ship 


    public void createBoard(){                                                      // draws the battleship game board
        for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++) {
                System.out.print(board[row][col] + "\t");

            } // inner loop
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
        } // outer loop
}

    public String getUserGuess() {                                                  // takes the users guess

        System.out.println("Choose a coordinate on the board to fire at");
        int x = input.nextInt();                                                        
        int y = input.nextInt();

        String userGuess = board[x][y];
        return userGuess;
    }



    public void checkResult(String userGuess) {                                     // checks the user's guess

            if(userGuess.equalsIgnoreCase(frigate[0])){
                System.out.println("hit!");
                numOfHitsOnFrigate++;
                board[1][1] = " *";
                createBoard();
            }
            else if(userGuess.equalsIgnoreCase(frigate[1])) {
                System.out.println("hit!");
                numOfHitsOnFrigate++;
                board[1][2] = " *";
                createBoard();
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("miss!");
            }
            if (numOfHitsOnFrigate == 2) {
                System.out.println("Enemy frigate has been sunk!");
                frigateIsAlive = false;
            }

        } 



} // end class


public class Game {

public static void run() {
    GameBoard newGame = new GameBoard();

    newGame.createBoard();

    while(newGame.frigateIsAlive) {
    newGame.checkResult(newGame.getUserGuess());
    }






    }

}


public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Game.run();

    }
}
```

Comment: Looks to me like the strings at (1, 1) and (1, 2) are the same as all the other board strings..?

Comment: Well the frigate is located at (1,1) and (1,2), (at least for the time being while I test the code), I am trying to enter those coordinates and register a hit on the ship.

Comment: To me, it looks like the idea of how the game could be programmed may be a bit off. Why not have two coordinates instead of the huge board? By issuing the ` frigate = {board[1][1], board[1][2]}`, you are assigning empty brackets to those spots, instead of anything of value. Then, I believe you are comparing those values to more empty brackets?

Comment: There's a much easier way to do what you want. Your board is already a matrix of String, so you could just place the name of the ship in the board, and where there are no ships, place the String "water." This way, you don't have to an extra String called "frigate" to keep track of locations. The board already records the location of ships, so why does a ship have to also track the same information? Now when you check for hits, all you have to do is if(board[x][y].equals("frigate"){frigateLife--}

Comment: Thus, there are only being empty brackets being compared. I think moving this to a proper scope and something of two points like on a graph may help..

Comment: @MarsAtomic

I think I have a vague idea of what you are suggesting. 

Now what if I want different ships to take up different amount of space. For example, the frigate should take up two (x,y) coordinates and another ship (like a battleship) should take up four. How would I go about implementing this?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer That conversation would be somewhat more involved. Feel free to open a chat with me if you would like a quick discussion.

Comment: @MarsAtomic

That would be great, but I don't how to start a chat with another user

Comment: I believe I answered this to as far as possible, @Cherry_Developer Is that not what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boat is always being hit because the declaration of `frigate` is:

```
  frigate = {board[1][1], board[1][2]}
```

, which is ultimately assigning the string `'[ ]'` to both values of the frigate. This is then being compared to more empty strings, when you are looking for the frigate and comparing the values.

This can be fixed by making a board of position x in `[1,2,3,4, n]` and y in `[A,B,C...,Letter_n]`. That is, the coordinates of the frigate would be `Frigate.x = 1` and `Frigate.y = A`.

I hope this helps!

---

I saw your further question of how to implement this. I would make Frigate a class that has a list of coordinates:

1. `this.x` as one point either Letter or Number
2. `this.y` as one point Not of type this.x as in your example
3. The tuple `(this.x, this.y)` would work nice in your list Frigate
4. Do the same for any other points in the list Frigate.

After the list Frigate has been completed, then two more things have to be changed.

The first thing that has be changed is how to check if the user is calling things in the scope that you want.

The second thing that has to be changed is how to make sure the same point isn't being called over and over again to 'blow up' a ship. That is, when a point in Frigate gets called, then **it should be removed from Frigate**. The remaining tuples in Frigate are going to be the 'health' of 'hit points' left on Frigate. To recall the original size of Frigate, an addition of `Frigate.initialSize()` would be very handy, but this could be later down the road.

Comment: The board is just for show. Something for the user to be able to see where the ship is and the hits. I get what you are saying though. The frigate and board should be two independent entities. Right?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer Yeah, exactly. The Frigate should be an object to itself, as should the board. The board should only be a medium to the Frigate. If you are wanting to reprint the board every time, then I would recommend doing what you are doing with the board, but just updating a hit to a `*` instead of the space or something. The best solution is the simplest solution :)